# How can we bundle our library files in Excelsior jet 10.0 software installer?

Tags: installation

I am using Excelior software to create installer of my desktop application. but I cant 
      find an option to bind library files with jar file in the Excelsior software. please 
       share your idea how to use library with application jar.